# Correct flatMapvalues in Kafka streams split single message based on a field value

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

Needing some guidance w.r.t Kafka streams split.

I have a message value fields like this

```
{"name": "val1", "role": "val2"}
```

key of the message is a String field which we don't worry about here.

When in the `name` field I get multiple values separated by a */* like this  `{"name": "tom/dick/harry", "role": "manager"}` I want to be able to check those records in my stream with multiple / separated values in name field and then split or branch based that and send each message to the output topic. So basically 1 message to 3 different messages in this case:

```
{"name": "tom", "role": "manager"}
{"name": "dick", "role": "manager"}
{"name": "harry", "role": "manager"}
```

and send each of these to output topic.

I have tried Kafka streams' `flatMapValues()` and `branch` but it doesn't work. Just looking for a one line code or method I can use to achieve this.
Here is my code:

```
modifiedStream.filter(((key, value) -> value.getPerformerName().contains("/")))
                .peek((key, value) -> log.info("Splitting this record to multiple ones..."))
                .flatMapValues(new ValueMapper<work_reg_performer_int, Iterable<?>>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public Iterable<?> apply(work_reg_performer_int value) {
                                       return Arrays.asList(value.getPerformerName().split("/"));
                                   }
                               }
                ).to("split_performers_topic");
```

Here is my consumer's stream config:

```
consumer:
                keySerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
                valueSerde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
                startOffset: earliest
```

Running this code is throwing this exception stack which I think is due to only each of the performer name becoming its own message without anything else?

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: ClassCastException while producing data to topic split_performers_topic. A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer / value: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerializer) is not compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: java.lang.String / value type: java.lang.String). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters (for example if using the DSL, `#to(String topic, Produced<K, V> produced)` with `Produced.keySerde(WindowedSerdes.timeWindowedSerdeFrom(String.class))`).
```

PS: I am using Spring Cloud stream for Kafka for this.

Comment: I added some code which I had left out

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your problem statement with Stream config values? From the error, you seem generating Streams of records with key of type String and value of type of avro specific record, but the expected format to the destination topic is String and String.

Also as per the code snippet you have hardcoded Stream out topic as "split_performers_topic", but in your error it is complaining about the producer topic APRADB_work_reg_performer. Not sure where is the mismatch coming from. Kindly check and confirm.

Comment: Hi @ChrisDist, I have updated my code with my stream config values, also my exceptions were from a different config run which I have now corrected the correct topic is split_performers_topic. 

Any idea how I can split 1 input message to multiple output messages based on the field value while passing each split of the field to one o/p message? 

Thank you for your help